# Google Cloud SQL column-level encryption

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

Does Google Cloud SQL support column-level encryption?

I know that it is possible for BigQuery tables but not sure about Cloud SQL!
[link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-key-encrypt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a out of the bow feature on Cloud SQL, you need to do it manually when you read and write the data. You can use Cloud KMS for hat.

With BigQuery, keep in mind that you need to keep the key in BigQuery also and only the IAM permission allow to access or not to the keyset.

Eventually, all the data are encrypted at rest, but I'm sure that your use case is for a specific column, not for the whole database.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! This info is what I was looking for.